# Determine maximum value of direction derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have never seen a question like this before and don't know how to start or proceed. How would one go about doing this? Thanks.

> Let $f(x,y,z)$ denote a differentiable function of three variables. It is known that $\partial f/\partial y = 9$ at the point $(1,5,21)$ and that the maximum value of the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(1,5,21)$ occurs in the direction of the vector $2\hat{i} + 3\hat{j} + 8\hat{k}$. Find the maximum value of the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(1,5,21)$. Give your answer corrected to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the directional derivative achieves its maximum in the direction of the gradient. So you know that it will be in the direction of $2i+3j+8k$. You want to scale that up by 3 to get the gradient, since the second component of the gradient is $f_y =9$. Thus the gradient is $6i+9j+24k$. Thus, the maximum a dot product of that with a unit vector will be the magnitude of that vector, which is $\sqrt{6^2+9^2+24^2}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!